# Selenium instagram photo upload does not happen

Tags: vb.net, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I'm trying to upload photos to Instagram with selenium. I've tried the following code I haven't found a fixed input, it works on other sites but there is no input in the click section and it doesn't get results for me

```
Dim fileuploadq As IWebElement

fileuploadq = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']"))

fileuploadq.SendKeys("C:\cristiano.jpg")
```

**The picture input as follows**

https://ibb.co/BtQJHpD

**I want to upload a picture without clicking the image upload button**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sure there is an file input element exist in the instangram?

Comment: @supputuri Yes There is 1 input

https://ibb.co/L66f0xc